# How to have an expandable CardView?

Tags: java, android, xml, cardview

I'm trying to develop an app right now that uses CardViews, and I'd like to have them be expandable; that is to say that upon someone pressing the CardView, it should expand to show more details. How would I go about doing this?

[image]

Here's a visual explanation of what i'm trying to do; when I press the highlighted CardView, I want it to expand to show more information, and be able to contract upon another press; I'm not sure how to do this, and searching the internet has led me to no answer as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is,use Expandable Layout and add it inside your CardView.

```
<com.kyo.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/child"
        app:canExpand="true" />
</com.kyo.expandable.ExpandableLayout>
```